# A trick for optional reference using universal references?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pass-by-reference, universal-reference

I've found a trick to use optional reference in standard C++11. 
Do you think that this technique is reliable and the behaviour is well defined according to the the C++ standard ?

```
// Optional reference using C++11 
// V. Reverdy - 2013
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T = int, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, int>::value>::type>
void f(T&& n = T())
{
    std::cout<<"--------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"is const = "<<std::is_const<T>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"is reference = "<<std::is_reference<T>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"is lvalue reference = "<<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"is rvalue reference = "<<std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"--------"<<std::endl;
    n *= 2;
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 42;
    std::cout<<"n = "<<n<<std::endl;
    f();
    std::cout<<"n = "<<n<<std::endl;
    f(n);
    std::cout<<"n = "<<n<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
n = 42
--------
is const = 0
is reference = 0
is lvalue reference = 0
is rvalue reference = 0
--------
n = 42
--------
is const = 0
is reference = 1
is lvalue reference = 1
is rvalue reference = 0
--------
n = 84
```

It seems to work on all compilers available on liveworkspace : [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3mCZla%240)

Comment: Do you have a real-world use-case for this?

Comment: The interesting part is that type type `T` varies between `int`, `int&`, `int&&` and `int const&`, with the `int` choice happening if you don't pass in anything.  The reason why we get `int` with no parameters is because the default value for the template argument is used, which means `T` is no longer deduced, and `T&&` is no longer being used in a type deduction context...  Try `std::is_reference<decltype(n)>::value` in that function -- the downside of your technique is that `T` is sometimes in a deduction context, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wat.

Firstly, what you have "achieved" could be far simpler achieved by, say, overloading. And secondly, it is not the same as an optional reference *at all*. The optional reference is a value, which may or may not contain a reference *at run-time*. The behaviour is well-defined but it's neither desirable nor an optional reference. Binding references to temporaries as default arguments is nice in some situations but it's a billion miles from an optional reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-defined, yes, because "*universal references*" (mind the fact that this is a non-standard term) can resolve into rvalue references and therefore bind to temporaries, but you're not creating an "*optional reference*".

References must always be initialized and must always be bound to an object, they cannot be "bound or not bound" (which is my intuitive understanding of what you mean by "*optional reference*").

Here, you are simply binding that reference to a temporary. What you did is equivalent to the following:

```
template<typename T> void f(T&& t) { ... }
void f() { f(int()); }
```

If you meant to say the you are now able to create a function which accepts a reference and may be invoked without providing any argument - which is IMO a more correct way to put it - then this is true, but I wouldn't consider it a breaking discovery.

Even in C++03 you could do something similar, although for references to `const` only:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T const& = T()) { ... }
```

Since C++11 introduced non-`const` references which can bind to temporaries (rvalue references), a natural generalization follows, which is what your technique exploits.